# sqlalchemy: alembic bulk insert fails: 'str' object has no attribute '_autoincrement_column'

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, alembic

My model looks like

```
class Category(UserMixin, db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'categories'
    uuid = Column('uuid', GUID(), default=uuid.uuid4, primary_key=True,
                  unique=True)
    name = Column('name', String, nullable=False)
    parent = Column('parent', String, nullable=False)
    created_on = Column('created_on', sa.types.DateTime(timezone=True),
                        default=datetime.utcnow())
    __table_args__ = (UniqueConstraint('name', 'parent'),)

    def __init__(self, name, parent):
        self.name = name
        self.parent = parent

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Category:%s:%s:%s>' % (
            self.uuid, self.name, self.category_type)
```

where [GUID](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/core/types.html#backend-agnostic-guid-type) is custom sqlalchemy type
I create the table using `alembic --autogenerate` option

```
 op.create_table('categories',
                    sa.Column('uuid', UUID(), nullable=False),
                    sa.Column('name', sa.String(), nullable=False),
                    sa.Column('parent', sa.String(), nullable=False),
                    sa.Column('created_on', sa.DateTime(timezone=True),
                              nullable=True),
                    sa.PrimaryKeyConstraint('uuid'),
                    sa.UniqueConstraint('name', 'parent'),
                    sa.UniqueConstraint('uuid')
    )
```

and PostgreSQL table as

```
            Table "public.categories"
   Column   |           Type           | Modifiers
------------+--------------------------+-----------
 uuid       | uuid                     | not null
 name       | character varying        | not null
 parent     | character varying        | not null
 created_on | timestamp with time zone |
Indexes:
    "categories_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (uuid)
    "categories_name_parent_key" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (name, parent)
```

I try to run the revision and update the db as

```
def upgrade():
    op.bulk_insert('categories',
                   [
                       {'name': 'first', 'parent': 'first_parent'},
                       {'name': 'second', 'parent': 'second_parent'}
                   ]
    )
```

when I run `alembic upgrade head`, I see error as

```
  File "/Users/me/.virtualenvs/envs/project/lib/python2.7/site-packages/alembic/environment.py", line 494, in run_migrations
    self.get_context().run_migrations(**kw)
  File "/Users/me/.virtualenvs/envs/project/lib/python2.7/site-packages/alembic/migration.py", line 211, in run_migrations
    change(**kw)
  File "alembic/versions/491d4f91e0bc_generate_categories_.py", line 21, in upgrade
    {'name': 'second', 'parent': 'second_parent'}
  File "<string>", line 7, in bulk_insert
  File "/Users/me/.virtualenvs/envs/project/lib/python2.7/site-packages/alembic/operations.py", line 710, in bulk_insert
    self.impl.bulk_insert(table, rows)
  File "/Users/me/.virtualenvs/envs/project/lib/python2.7/site-packages/alembic/ddl/impl.py", line 179, in bulk_insert
    table._autoincrement_column = None
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '_autoincrement_column'
```

What is that I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

all I had to do is to create a `table` before bulk_insert, even if I have a explicit schema in separate `models.py`

```
import sqlalchemy as sa
from sqlalchemy.sql import table
from alembic import op

def upgrade():
     categories = table('categories',
                       sa.Column('uuid', UUID(),
                              primary_key=True,
                              unique=True, autoincrement=False),
                       sa.Column('name', String),
                       sa.Column('parent', String),
                       sa.Column('created_on', sa.types.DateTime(timezone=True),
                              default=datetime.utcnow())
    )
    op.bulk_insert(categories,
                   [
                       {'name': 'first', 'parent': 'first_parent'},
                       {'name': 'second', 'parent': 'second_parent'}
                   ]
    )
```

and then I was able to to run `alembic upgrade head` without any issues and data was serialized successfully in database.

Comment: Note that this uses `sqlalchemy.sql.table` and **not** `alembic.op.create_table`. It took me a while to realise that `create_table` doesn't return anything. Moreover, the first parameter to `bulk_insert` is a `table` instance, not a `str`.

Comment: Note that @Jon 's comment is not relevant any more. The `op.create_table` returns the table object since version `0.7.0`. http://alembic.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ops.html#alembic.operations.Operations.create_table

Comment: Well you don't need to create the table in the revision file. You could have just done `category_table = my.project.models.categories.__table__`