# SQLalchemy: alembic bulk_insert() fails

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, alembic

Before you flag this as a duplicate:

I did take a look at this [question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15725859/sqlalchemy-alembic-bulk-insert-fails-str-object-has-no-attribute-autoincre), and I did do what it suggests, but when I do add this code:

```
permslookup = sa.Table('permslookup',
    sa.Column('perms_lookup_id', primary_key=True),
    sa.Column('name', sa.Unicode(40), index=True),
    sa.Column('description', sa.Text),
    sa.Column('value', sa.Numeric(10, 2)),
    sa.Column('ttype', sa.PickleType(), index=True),
    sa.Column('permission', sa.Unicode(40), index=True),
    sa.Column('options', sa.PickleType())
    )
```

and then run `alembic upgrade head`, I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: Neither 'Column' object nor 'Comparator' object has an attribute 'schema'
```

When I examine the full stack trace, I notice that This is causing the error:

```
sa.Column('options', sa.PickleType())
```

This is the last line of the above code... How can I resolve this? I have not a clue what how to solve it... Help of any kind would be appreciated.

Here is the data I want to insert:

```
op.bulk_insert('permslookup',
    [
        {
            'id': 1,
            'name': 'accounts',
            'description': """ Have permission to do all transactions """,
            'value': 1,
            'ttype': ['cash', 'loan', 'mgmt', 'deposit', 'adjustments'],
            'permission': 'accounts',
            'options': None
        },
        {
            'id': 2,
            'name': 'agent_manage',
            'description': """ Have permission to do cash, cash, loan and Management Discretion transactions """,
            'value': 2,
            'ttype': ['cash', 'loan', 'mgmt'],
            'permission': 'agent_manage',
            'options': None
        },
        {
            'id': 3,
            'name': 'corrections',
            'description': """ Have permission to do cash, loan and adjustments transactions """,
            'value': 3,
            'ttype': ['cash', 'loan', 'adjustments'],
            'permission': 'corrections',
            'options': None
        },
        {
            'id': 4,
            'name': 'cashup',
            'description': """ Have permission to do cash and loan transactions """,
            'value': 4,
            'ttype': ['cash', 'loan'],
            'permission': 'cashup',
            'options': None
        },

    ]
)
```

The original error I get when trying to run the `bulk_insert` is:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '_autoincrement_column'
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For error #1, not enough information.  Need a stack trace.

For #2, bulk_insert() receives the Table object, not a string name, as the argument.

see http://alembic.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ops.html#alembic.operations.Operations.bulk_insert:

```
from alembic import op
from datetime import date
from sqlalchemy.sql import table, column
from sqlalchemy import String, Integer, Date

# Create an ad-hoc table to use for the insert statement.
accounts_table = table('account',
    column('id', Integer),
    column('name', String),
    column('create_date', Date)
)

op.bulk_insert(accounts_table,
    [
        {'id':1, 'name':'John Smith',
                'create_date':date(2010, 10, 5)},
        {'id':2, 'name':'Ed Williams',
                'create_date':date(2007, 5, 27)},
        {'id':3, 'name':'Wendy Jones',
                'create_date':date(2008, 8, 15)},
    ]
)
```

Comment: When I created an object of the table, It worked. thanks `:)`

Answer (score 0):

For first error switch `sa.Table` and `sa.Column` with:

`from sqlalchemy.sql import table, column`